# Node server shuts down when terminal closed

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, forever, npm-start

I am trying to run my node server as a background process using forever. When I close the putty terminal the server still shuts down. What am I doing worng?

command: `forever -c "npm start &" ./`

package.json

```
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./bin/www",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
     .....
  }
}
```

Comment: you tried "forever start bin/www" ?

Comment: @GmoQuinteros Worked perfectly thank you!